# PayPal Transactions response getting delayed

Tags: api, paypal

I am creating PayPal transactions through UI and API, but getting the API response after 3 to 4 hours and some times next day.

So, it becomes tough to read the PayPal transactions through API.

Does anyone have any alternative solution for this? And Is this PayPal standard behavior, or am I missing anything from my end?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There are approximately 200 different PayPal APIs.  Which API are you referring to?

Comment: PayPal Transaction Search (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/)

Answer (score 1):

The transaction search API is for looking up a historical transactions occasionally

To be notified of recent/current transactions, you should be looking at an API capture response, or using webhooks, or the older IPN service.

Comment: Can you please point to the API documentation, that from where we can read the PayPal Transactions immediately?

Comment: Whatever API you are using to capture/execute transactions will give an immediate response, for example the newest one: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

Comment: If you want to subscribe to asynchronous webhook notifications instead (not recommended, but possible) see the possible event names at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/ -- for development purposes you should subscribe to all events with `*`and log what you receive, then build your logic and live subscriptions accordingly